# how to open python project in visual studio 2012?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-2012, ide, ptvs

I am new to python. I have downloaded a python project from this website.. **native python v.1.3.1**

http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~hugo/conceptnet/#download

Also I have installed PTVS 2.1 VS2012, python-2.7.10 in my windows system. 
If I go to the source folder where I downloaded python, its not showing solution file (like VS project). I understand that its not developed in VS. But when I try to open, Project from Existing code (File->New->Project from Existing code), I'm not able to see python IDE even though I installed python.

Is there any other way to open the entire project from one solution file through VS 2012? Any help would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 6):

Well, I followed these steps and it showed properly highlighted python code:

1. Downloaded and installed VS 2015 Community edition, selecting to add python support during the install process.
2. File -> New -> Project.
3. Expanded Installed, Templates, Python.  Selected `From Existing Python code`.
4. Under `Enter or browse to the folder containing your Python code`, I selected a folder that contains .py files.
5. In Solution Explorer, it shows the folder.  Selected a .py file, which is shown in the main pane.

To make sure everything was working ok, I saved and closed, then reopened the .sln file by double-clicking in File Explorer.  VS apparently recognizes it as a python project, and IntelliSense is working.  Actually it seems to be quite helpful -- I might use this in the future.

If you followed these steps, which seems to be the case, then your edition of Visual Studio might be too old.  [The instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation) recommend VS2015, even though there is a download for VS2012.